# using heroku to deploy an app? Basic queries

Tags: python, html, heroku, flask

Ok, I started with flask and heroku, and I went on to learn more, I am extremely naive as I just started it today. I found this brilliant blog by Ryan Shea,

http://ryaneshea.com/lightweight-python-apps-with-flask-twitter-bootstrap-and-heroku

This particular blog explains the following,

1> what is flask and heroku 
2> how to create and write and connect to heroku using CL.

I followed it because it was extremely easy, I had a lot of problems in the middle regarding the ssh keys and creating procfile etc, I used SO to figure it out.

What I did-->

I created virtualenv, then i typed the app.py , created procfile and also the req.txt file. 
I connected to heroku and created a stack cedar, renamed it too.

Then comes the HTML files, there is one base.html , then one index and 404 html files.
I typed all of them and saved them. Then When I run the code,

```
python app.py
```

The code runs,
I try to connect to the IP from different computer on the same network, it gets connected and it prints

' Hello from python'

Which was the first

```
@app.route("/")
 return 'Hello from python'
```

My question is, why isnt the base.html or the other html files exist?
I understood how the app was successfully deployed in heroku, but what are the other html files and how do they work?
Please refer to the above link and answer my questions. 
I am really naive and do bare it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are just starting out with Flask I would recommend you read [The Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) by Miguel Grinberg.  The tutorial goes through the development of a web app, including deployment to Heroku, and does a good job of explaining why and how different methods are used.

Regarding your question, Flask uses .html files as templates using the Jinja 2 template engine, which has a markup syntax similar to Django's.  In order to use a template you need to call it with one of Flask's template rendering hooks, most commonly [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template).  You can see that `render_template` is used in the guide you linked here (third from last code block):

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

This tells Flask to generate a page using the 'index.html' template located in the templates folder relative to `app.py`.